# Referencing chained Pandas DF in intermediary step

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to join two data frames and drop overlapping column(s) in a single series of chained operations:

```
# people.head()
  | name    | id
  |---------|----
0 | Jacob   | 150
1 | Richard | 160
2 | John    | 230
3 | Kate    | 420
4 | Hugo    | 1080

# age.head()
  | age  | id
  |------|---
0 | 1024 | 15
1 | 128  | 16
2 | 56   | 23
3 | 32   | 42
4 | 24   | 108

combined = people.join(age, lsuffix='_TO_DROP_')
# combined.head()
  | name    | age  | id  | id_TO_DROP
  |---------|------|-----|-----------
0 | Jacob   | 1024 | 15  | 150
1 | Richard | 128  | 16  | 160
2 | John    | 56   | 23  | 230
3 | Kate    | 32   | 42  | 420
4 | Hugo    | 24   | 108 | 1080
```

I can now drop any duplicated column(s) caused by the `join` with

```
combined.drop(columns=[col for col in combined.columns if col.endswith('_TO_DROP_'])
```

Is there a way to do this with chaining the `join` and `drop` ops?

```
people\
  .join(age, lsuffix='_TO_DROP_')\
  .drop(columns=[col for col in INTERMED_DF.columns if col.endswith('_TO_DROP_')])
```

Concretely, within the chained `drop` call, how do I access the output of the previous (chained) `join` call?

## Edit

Another detail to my use case: the overlapping column(s) don't exactly line up. The column that the data should be joined on is the data frame index, so in my example, just merging (or joining) on the `id` column wouldn't accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way :

I am chaining the `join` with [`df.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) which takes a regex parameter:

> regex : string (regular expression)
>   Keep labels from axis for which re.search(regex, label) == True

```
people.join(age, lsuffix='_TO_DROP_').filter(regex='^(?!.*TO_DROP_)')
```

---

```
       name     age    id
0    Jacob      1024     15
1    Richard    128      16
2    John       56       23
3    Kate       32       42
4    Hugo       24      108
```

Comment: Nice. After posting my question, I looked into it and saw that there's the `pipe` function, which, although does what I want, seems harder to read than adding a second statement to drop the columns. Using `filter` does what I want, and feels natural to read in a chain.

Answer (score 2):

try finding the columns which are not overlapping by taking `difference`and passing that list in df when joining it

```
people=pd.DataFrame(data={"name":["jacob","richard"],
                     "id":[15,6]})
age = pd.DataFrame(data={"age":[1024,128],
                        "id":[15,6]})

cols_to_use = age.columns.difference(people.columns)
combined = people.join(age[cols_to_use])
```

```
    name    id  age
0   jacob   15  1024
1   richard  6  128
```

Answer (score 1):

according to pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

`people.join(age.set_index('id'), on='id')` should work

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23765025)

Comment: `just merging (or joining) on the id column wouldn't accomplish what I want.` so your answer is wrong according to the question